# sessionId in a Lambda function can be the ID of an Alexa skill?

Tags: aws-lambda, alexa-skills-kit, aws-iot

I have a skill developed in Alexa which is linked with a lambda function in AWS.

In the lambda function when I start the session I have the following function:

```js
/**
 * Called when the session starts.
 */
function onSessionStarted(sessionStartedRequest, session)
{
    console.log("Session starts");
    console.log(`onSessionStarted requestId = ${sessionStartedRequest.requestId}, sessionId = ${session.sessionId}`);
}
```

Can sessionID be linked to the alexa account ID of who ran the skill?

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know, the sessionId is a randomly generated ID and most probably Amazon will keep it linked to the skillId and the userId but that information is not made available to the developers.